# MapFragment not displaying since release

Tags: android, google-maps

I have an app that makes use of MapFragment and while I was developing the app the map worked perfectly fine.

I recently created a signed apk and uploaded my app to the app store for alpha testing. Since then the maps in app are not showing anything. The odd thing is that not only are maps not being shown in the release version, but when I run the app through android studio it's not showing there either.

I've added my SHA1 fingerprint from my keystore and still nothing working.

Here is some of my code:

```
<permission
    android:name="com.k.myapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.k.myapp.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
    android:name="com.k.myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.k.myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:name=".myappApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="MY_ANDROID_API_KEY" />
```

My layout file - This layout displays the map in a small rectangle inside the activity

```
    <fragment
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:id="@+id/map_detail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    map:cameraZoom="13"
    map:mapType="normal"
    map:liteMode="true"
    tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"/>
```

My Activity:

```
    SupportMapFragment fragment = (SupportMapFragment)
                        getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_detail);
                mGoogleMap = fragment.getMap();

markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                markerOptions.position(latLng);

                mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
```

I also have google play services:

```
compile 'com.google.android.'
```

In addition to this I have an activity with a full screen map. This map randomly works for 1 of my users but not the rest. I don't think there is a problem with my code, but I've tried everything in terms of adding SHA1 fingerprints from my keystore. What's even more bizare to me is why the map isn't even working in development.

Comment: confirm your API_KEY is correct, debug builds and production builds use different keys

Comment: I added my release SHA1 to the allowed android applications. Is there something else I'm supposed to do?

Comment: Install the production apk on device (adb install file.apk), test maps.  Does it work?

Comment: nope, doesn't work on the production version or the development version

Comment: Please try to follow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ADb5bNOFHE) step by step, it will set up `SHA1`, and you will finally get a map on your phone.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having a pair of keys in my manifest, one for production and the other for debug (as CSmsith suggested).

In case you don't know where to find your debug keystore, search your hard drive for debug.keystore.

Good luck!